# Angular2 Router does not work on initial load of the application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am having a strange issue since I updated to angular's latest router(3.0.0-beta.2)

If I execute this code

```
this._router.navigate(['/login']);
```

anywhere in my app it works fine except the first time a user navigates to the page, and a redirect is needed for him to log in.
No error is thrown, it just simply does not redirect.

Here is my code:

main.ts file:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ApplicationConfiguration, provide(Http, {
  useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router, appConfig: ApplicationConfiguration) => new HttpServiceLayer(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router, appConfig),
  deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, ApplicationConfiguration]
})]);
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private appConfig: ApplicationConfiguration,  private _router: Router) {
if (!this.appConfig.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
 }
}

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'login', component: LogInComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

It may be that I am not doing something correct, but this code used to work before the update.

Does any body know why the router would not redirect the user to the log in page?

Any help is appreciated.

**Solution:**
Using a Guard on the dashboard route should do the trick.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'login', component: LogInComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [DashboardGuard]},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];

@Injectable()
export class DashboardGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private appConfig: ApplicationConfiguration, private _router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (this.appConfig.isUserLoggedIn()) { return true; }
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

And in main.ts you need to add the DashboardGuard as a provider.

Comment: Anything in the browser console?

Comment: Like I said, none... My feeling is that for some reason, may be something is not yet loaded? If you need me to provide anything else, please let me know. Also, if my method of redirecting a user is not good, please let me see a template/example on how to do it the best way.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read properly :-/

Comment: You could try a `setTimeout()` around `this.router.navigate()`. Might be changing route in the constructor causes issues.

Comment: I also was thinking of that, but it does seem like a dirty fix, isn't it ? Also, I tried changing the route from ngOnInit and from ngOnAfterInit or something like that, still same effect.

Comment: I know, people don't like `setTimeout()`, but IMHO it's only bad if you rely on some specific time having passed. In this case I wouldn't consider it dirty. It would just allow Angular to finish initialization before the navigation call gets executed - enqueue the call to be done after the current event queue is processed. I see it more like "get in line" instead of "queue jumping" ;-)

Comment: You might trying putting a generic `CanActivate` instead of trying to navigate from the `AppComponent`. Also, what url are you typing in? maybe there is a conflict between the `redirectTo` and the `navigate`. Last suggestion; I don't think that it should matter, but maybe try moving `ApplicationConfiguration` ahead of `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in the bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Guard on the dashboard route should do the trick.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'login', component: LogInComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [DashboardGuard]},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];

@Injectable()
export class DashboardGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private appConfig: ApplicationConfiguration, private _router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (this.appConfig.isUserLoggedIn()) { return true; }
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that also, with no effect. I will try and make a plunker

Comment: I have also tried using the ngOnInit and still the same effect

Comment: Glad to hear that  :)